# how to use the global variable value defined in block outside block in Swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, block

I have a variable defined globally that when accessed inside a block with self.lastReading, it's not getting value defined in block. how to get that value defined in block?

```
var lastReading = 0

Query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock(

{(data:PFObject?,error:NSError?) -> Void in

var dataEntry = data!

var Reading: AnyObject! = dataEntry["reading"]!

self.lastReading = Reading.integerValue
})
```

Edit: lastReading variable is global variable defined inside the class.

Comment: What's the point of the lastReading variable declared outside your block? And what do you mean when you say it's not getting the value? When are you testing this

Comment: I want to use the lastReading value retrieved from Parse database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like:

```
var lastReading = 0
```

is defined inside a class (better add context code to know where it is defined). If that is the case, you're probably executing your block / closure in a different thread. So:

1. you set lastReading = 0
2. you launch some time-consuming task in another thread. The main thread (or the thread running that code) continues executing immediately. At the end of the block, you assign lastReading.
3. if you check lastReading just after the block, nothing *changes*. Still == 0. That's because Main thread executes immediately and lastReading hasn't changed.

I'd better call a method to update lastReading at the end of the block:

```
var lastReading = 0

Query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock(

    {(data:PFObject?,error:NSError?) -> Void in

    var dataEntry = data!

    var Reading: AnyObject! = dataEntry["reading"]!

    self.updatelastReading(Reading.integerValue)
})
```

Comment: lastReading variable is defined inside class but outside the function. you can say it's global variable. Using your solution I'm getting the correct value for the variable inside the method but not inside the function which has the block. possibly as block query is running in background, data is not available from parse when line of code executing within the block. Is there anyway, I can trigger the code after completion of the background query. I know we can use Query.getFirstObject() but that's not efficient code.